# How to handle patch request with unset value in golang

Tags: rest, go, patch, go-gorm

I am working on a patch restful request that the body json contain some omitted value while sending to golang. Since an unset value will lead the golang struct become default value. So I would like to know if there are any solution to deal with patch request omit data?

As I know, a basic type like string / int cannot be nullable in golang. there are different approach to deal with unset value patch request. For example:

1. using pointer to deal with null problem

   ```
   type User struct {
       Name *string
   }
   ```
2. using nullable library

   ```
   type User struct {
       Name  sql.NullString
   }
   ```
3. using `map[string][]interface{}` to see if the value is set

Is there any better solution to deal with nullable value inside struct? since this 3 should be work around to deal with the nullable value.

Comment: The only other possibility is that if you have the value you want to patch already loaded, e.g. from db, you can unmarshal into that and fields that were omitted in the json will not be overwritten on the value. https://play.golang.org/p/zyTtrqyRZJp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pointer along with the `omitempty` tag. This way you can differentiate between an unset value, nil, and an intentional zero value ("", false, 0).

```
type User struct {
    Name *string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VZAEEfM6gNm)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes it is a possible way to do. But I would like to know any reason behind to not suggest using nullable lib? p.s I am thinking about which solution is better but don’t really know which one would be better

Comment: Well, it's another dependency.  I don't know whether that would be a problem for you. The way I suggested it's standard (no libs required).

Comment: And it seems kind of silly to use a 3rd party library, considering pointers are a nullable (well, `nil`able) type built in to the language.

Comment: You are right, using 3rd party lib to do this kind of duty is really stupid... I should consider using pointer instead

Answer (score 16):

If you're using `PATCH` in a RESTful way, that means it's updating some existing data, and only overwriting those fields included in the request body. Which means you don't actually need to know which fields are set or not; you can just load your canonical object and unmarshal over it to replace any fields that are found in the JSON, while leaving any others untouched:

```
canonObj := getObjectFromDBOrSomething()
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(canonObj)
```

This will overwrite any fields in `canonObj` with fields from the request, but any fields *not* in the request won't be touched.

Comment: This method really magic, does not realise we can do the job like this

Comment: Don't forget to pass an address (`&canonObj`) as it may not be a pointer.

Comment: Pass an address *if* it's not a pointer. If it's already a pointer, pass it as is.

Comment: This is a good solution provided you expect the client to update any field in `canonObj`. What if there are fields that must not be updated (say `id`). I feel @hlscalon answer above makes sense in such a case unless am missing something.

Comment: `getObjectFromDBOrSomething` is likely to be expensive. Better to use @hlscalon's answer so the struct can be validated before pulling data from the DB. It is a good tip if it meets your use case though.

Comment: @jbrown potentially, but it assumes that a) `getObjectFromDBOrSomething` is in fact expensive, and b) validation doesn't need the other fields filled (all fields validated in isolation). Neither of those are clear from the question, so either answer might serve different cases.

Comment: this will also suffer from race conditions if multiple clients are updating the same data ?

Comment: @othane possibly, there's not enough context to say and it's beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: @Adrian I think it will unless you lock the database between reading the object and setting the fields, which incur quite a large performance penalty. A college of mine suggested this if your writing your own sql which is quite nice https://medium.com/developer-rants/conditional-update-in-postgresql-a27ddb5dd35

Comment: @othane it doesn't even say what database they're using. If they're using transactions, it's a total non-issue, with a minimal performance impact. Again, there is not enough context to say, and it's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @adrian yes, but my point is in your answer you read from the DB, so you must take the write back to the DB into account too (PATCH required this). And that would produce a race condition using this method (another request could change the object between your read and write, and those changes would be totally lost). The only ways to avoid this are to use a single DB transaction by using hlscalon answer with something like the link in my previous comment, or to lock the table around the read and write in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is writing your own type, and implement [json.Unmarshaller](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type NullString struct {
    Data string
    Null bool
}

func (ns *NullString) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    if string(d) == "null" {
        // this is based on your need. you may add a new field here
        ns.Null = true
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(d, &ns.Data)
}

type Test struct {
    Data1 NullString `json:"data1"`
    Data2 NullString `json:"data2"`
    Data3 NullString `json:"data3"`
}

const t = `{"data1":null, "data2":"string"}`

func main() {
    p := Test{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(t), &p)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", p)
}
```

result is `{Data1:{Data: Null:true} Data2:{Data:string Null:false} Data3:{Data: Null:false}}` if the value is `null` then the Null field is set. also you can simply add extra fields to this struct if needed. for example a field to track if the function is called or not.

ps : also see the [json.Marshaller](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) for the reverse from struct to json.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VYhggRGH3ai)